# Generate nullable C# property in Visual Studio 2013 from UML class diagram

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-generation

I would like to ask some help regarding code generating in VS 2013.

I have a class which has nullable properties. First of all, it is possible to set up nullable if the property is only collection. What if the property is int?

I went through the MSDN pages but there is no info about this case. On the other hand, it seems only I have this issue because Google does not give usable answers.

Shall I write my classes by hand or shall I create my own t4 files to solve this issue?

Comment: Bah, it is possible just simply overwrite the drop down list values. So that, I can overwrite the selected "Integer" to "int?" and it is working fine. Code generating is working also fine.

I took a try with EA 11 and the solutions there - I spent 20 minutes with it - is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible just simply overwrite the drop down list values. So that, I can overwrite the selected "Integer" to "int?" and it is working fine. Code generating is working also fine.